# I'm trying to track how long a players mouse is on top of a circle while its moving but I'm always getting the total time the program was run

Tags: python, time, pygame, mouse

As said above I want to track the time a mouse is inside a moving circle. I am recording the time at whenever the mouse leaves the circle and subtracting the last time the mouse left the circle(or the start if it was the first time) but whenever I add those times I get a number around the total time the program was run(10 seconds).
This is the code I'm running:

```
import pygame
import time
import random
import math
from time import perf_counter_ns as timer

pygame.init()
  
# Define the background colour
# using RGB color coding.
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (255, 10, 75)
  
# Define the dimensions of
# screen object(width,height)
screenx = 1200
screeny = 1000
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenx, screeny))
  
# Set the caption of the screen
pygame.display.set_caption('Geeksforgeeks')
  
# Fill the background colour to the screen
screen.fill(black)
  
# Update the display using flip
pygame.display.flip()
  
# Variable to keep our game loop running
running = True

end = 10
nano = 1000000000

def clear_screen():
    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.display.flip()

class circle():
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.velocity = random.randint(1, 10)
        self.theta = random.randint(0, 360)
        self.radius = radius
        self.alive = False
        
    def draw_circle(self, radius):
        self.x = random.randint(0, screenx)
        self.y = random.randint(0, screeny)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, red, (random.randint(0, 1200), random.randint(0, 1200)), radius)
        pygame.display.update()
        self.alive = True

    def move_circle(self):
        clear_screen()
        self.x += self.velocity * math.cos(self.theta)
        self.y += self.velocity * math.sin(self.theta)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, red, (self.x, self.y), self.radius)
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(0.1)

    def change_velocity(self):
        self.velocity = random.randint(1, 1)
        self.theta = random.randint(0, 360)

    def check_collision(self):
        if (self.x - self.radius) < 0 or (self.x + self.radius) > screenx:
            self.x = random.randint(0, screenx)
        if (self.y - self.radius) < 0 or (self.y + self.radius) > screeny:
            self.y = random.randint(0, screeny)

    def mouse_in_red(self, mouse_x, mouse_y):
        if (mouse_x - self.x)**2 + (mouse_y - self.y)**2 < self.radius**2:
            return True
        else:
            return False

target = circle(25)
# game loop
start = timer()
crnt_time = start
times = [start]
target.draw_circle(25)
while running:
    if target.alive == False:
        target.draw_circle(25)
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        if random.randint(0, 100) == 1:
            target.change_velocity()
        target.move_circle()
        target.check_collision()
        if target.mouse_in_red(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0], pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]):
            print('hit')
            continue
        else:
            print(f'miss',{(timer() - crnt_time)/nano})
            times.append(timer() - crnt_time)
            crnt_time = timer()
    if (timer() - start)/nano > end:
        running = False
        print(f'total time spent on target(out of ',{end},'seconds):', {(sum(times[1:]))/nano})
        print(f'average time spent on target:', {(sum(times[1:])/len(times[1:]))/nano})
        #for i in range(len(times[1:])):
        #    print(f'time spent on target {i}:', {(times[i])/nano})
    # for loop through the event queue  
    for event in pygame.event.get():
    
        # Check for QUIT event      
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

and this is the final output I'm getting(not including hit and miss debug and times list prints)

```
total time spent on target(out of  {10} seconds): {10.0042299}
average time spent on target: {0.22736886136363638}
```

I tried commenting out the move_circle function and just using a still circle but for some reason that didn't register any hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reset `crnt_time` every frame, and actually count the time the cursor is on top the circle.

I simplified your a code a little bit and made it a bit more "pygamey" by using pygame's `Clock` and changing the class to look more idiomatic (`draw`/`update`-pattern).

As you can see, we simply calculate the delta time (`dt`) every frame, and if the cursor is on top of the circle, we add the current delta time to `time_on_top`. When the cursor leaves the circle or the program ends, we add the accumulated time to `times`:

```
import pygame
import time
import random
import math

pygame.init()
screenx = 1200
screeny = 1000
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenx, screeny))
pygame.display.set_caption('Geeksforgeeks')
running = True
end = 10

class Circle():
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.color = 'red'
        self.velocity = random.randint(1, 10)
        self.theta = random.randint(0, 360)
        self.radius = radius
        self.alive = False
        self.x = random.randint(0, screenx)
        self.y = random.randint(0, screeny)

    def update(self):
        if random.randint(0, 100) == 1:
            self.velocity = random.randint(1, 1)
            self.theta = random.randint(0, 360)
            
        self.x += self.velocity * math.cos(self.theta)
        self.y += self.velocity * math.sin(self.theta)
        
        if (self.x - self.radius) < 0 or (self.x + self.radius) > screenx:
            self.x = random.randint(0, screenx)
        if (self.y - self.radius) < 0 or (self.y + self.radius) > screeny:
            self.y = random.randint(0, screeny)
        
    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.radius)

target = Circle(25)
times = []

dt = 0
time_on_top = 0
total_time = 0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# game loop
while running:
    # 1. part of the loop: event handling
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Check for QUIT event      
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # 2. part of the loop: draw everything
    # no need to define basic colors yourself
    screen.fill('black')
    target.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()            
    
    # 3. part of the loop: update logic
    target.update()
    mpos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if math.hypot(mpos[0] - target.x, mpos[1] - target.y) < target.radius:
        # if mouse is top of circle? count delta times
        time_on_top += dt 
        target.color = 'green'
    else:
        # mouse was on top of circle? add time to times
        if time_on_top > 0:
            times.append(time_on_top)
        target.color = 'red'
        time_on_top = 0
    
    dt = clock.tick(60)    
    total_time += dt
    
    if total_time >= end * 1000:
        if time_on_top > 0:
            times.append(time_on_top)
        running = False

print(f'total time spent on target (out of {end} seconds): {sum(times)/1000}')
print(f'average time spent on target: {sum(times)/len(times)/1000 if times else 0}')
```